# Polynomial: Finding its value

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> If $a-b=3$, $a+b+x=2$, then find the value of $(a-b)\left(x^3-2ax^2+a^2x-(a+b)b^2\right)$

I could only substitute the value of $a-b$ there. I seriously want to try as much as I can on my own but I don't even know where to start.

I tried [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a-b%29%5Bx%5E3-2ax%5E2%2Ba%5E2x-%28a%2Bb%29b%5D) but it seems to mess up the polynomial completely.

Can someone please give me some two/three starting steps ?

**EDIT:**

I figured out that $$2a = 5-x$$And that $$a+b=2-x$$but am not getting the solution. Any further steps that may take to the solution are welcome.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try using $(a+b+x)^3 = 2^3$.

Comment: @LeifSabellek Not able to do. Can you please elaborate. Thanks :)

Comment: There is a $x^3$ in the term you want to calculate. So you take $(a+b+x)=2$ and take it to the third power. When you multiply out, you could maybe get something similar to what you can substitute. If not, you could try substituting $b=a-3$ first, so you get $2a-3+x=2$. Then you could take this to the third power.

Comment: @LeifSabellek I used the latter equation and got $8a^3-125+x^3+30x$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Set up the matrix below based on the givens of your problem.

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}2{} & 0{} & 1{} & 5 \\0 &2 & 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

Solve the matrix to get the following solution set:

$$\left\{(a, b, x)= \left(\left(\frac{5}{2} - \frac{x}{2}\right), \left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right), x\right) \Bigg| x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

So you can set $x$ to any real number to arrive at the values of $a$ and $b$ and your polynomial takes on an infinite number of values depending on the value of $x$.